# Can't use int(input())'s

Tags: python

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())


print(x, y, z)
```

When I input y an error shows up:
**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

I didn't know what to try so I just messed around and when I did the following it somehow worked

```
x = int(input())
print(x)
y = int(input())
print(y)
z = int(input())
print(z)

print(x, y, z)
```

so my question is why it doesn't work without prints

So apparently PYCharm is the problem. When I input the same numbers in VSC or any online python compiler I get what I input. I guess I won't be using PYCharm anymore.

Comment: And what are you typing into stdin?

Comment: "When I input y an error shows up:" - because you entered, as the message clearly states, an "invalid literal for int() with base 10". Enter valid numbers and all will be fine, as happened in your second example...

Comment: The print have nothing to do witht hat. If you type the same input, one number per line, it'll work

Comment: I've put 1 as an input to all 3 inputs. nothing much nothing more

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently wrong with what you're doing, you can pass the result of `input()` into `int()`:

```
>>> x = int(input())
123
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
>>> x
123
```

The error that you're getting indicates that you're passing something which isn't a number into `int()`.

```
>>> int("hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'
```

So the issue is with what you were entering into the `input()` prompt. If you added whitespace (i.e. spaces, newlines, that sort of thing) then `int()` is fine with that, but if you entered any letters or other characters then you'd be out of luck.

Hopefully that explains the error you were seeing. If you believe you were entering only digits and you got that error, it would be helpful to see a paste of the console session so I can take a look and explain what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

In both code samples you will receive the error if you give a value that cannot be converted to integer, for example:

```
"asd"
"!"
" "
"12lorem"
```

Make sure you give number string as an input

Comment: Yes, i've been putting numbers to stdin